# Not getting all notifications from Facebook SDK, Graph-API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am making an application and I need to get all new notifications from Facebook. I succesfully login and get manage_notifications permission to my App. This piece of code succesfuly load JSON string from facebook.

```
Session session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        Request notificationsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(
                session, "/me/notifications",
                new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        GraphObject object = response
                                .getGraphObject();
                        if (object != null) {
                            notificationsNewString = object
                                    .getInnerJSONObject()
                                    .toString();

                            try {
                                notificationsOldString = saver.getJsonFromInternalCache();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                notificationsOldString = null;
                            }
                            try {
                                compareOldAndNewData();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            createNotif();

                        } else {
                            notificationsNewString = "Notifications returns null";
                        }

                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAndWait(notificationsRequest);
    } else {
        Log.i("TAGTAG", "Session not open!");
    }
```

But some people have difficulties with app, because Facebook dont send in json all new notifications. Especially notification if someone comments on status that they comment. (On Facebook it is marked like a new notification, but json is empty).

Its about some permissions or it is bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello,I am having the same issue, I have created a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1438457359755749/

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. I will post it in case somebody finds it helpful

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
if (state.isOpened()) {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Request(session,"/me/notifications", null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (object != null) {
                            InboxMessage.setText(object.getProperty("data").toString());
                        } else {
                            InboxMessage.setText("Notifications returns null");
                        }
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
} else {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
}
}
```